# How to search list of dictionary in mysql column(datatype is JSON)

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

My data format looks like as below in a column in **mysql** db:

```
|column1| column2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| [{"id": 1, "name": "American"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Indian"}]|
| 2| [{"id": 2, "name": "Indian"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Britain"}]|
| 3| [{"id": 4, "name": "Indian"}, {"id": 5, "name": "Britain"}]|
```

Search by id's (2,3) in column2 should give the expected output as below.

```
|column1| column2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| [{"id": 1, "name": "American"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Indian"}]|
| 2| [{"id": 2, "name": "Indian"}, {"id": 3, "name": "Britain"}]|
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what is exactly that you have and what is exactly that you expect

Comment: Hey is it more clear now ?

Comment: encounter with the same issue, any solutions to sovle it?